# Bootstrap Responsive Grid: Avoid padding left on grid-element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

i am designing a website with bootstrap and i have a problem: The first element in the responsive grid has an unintended padding-left by 15px.

Can you tell me how to fix that? Thanx!

Here's the website:

http://muviko.de/

And here's the code:

```
<div class="container mtop50">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="img/platzhalter.png"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="img/platzhalter.png"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="img/platzhalter.png"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="img/platzhalter.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have padding on each container. And also on columns. Thats why.

You can remove the padding from the container with blue squares

Comment: Thanks! I've added a class that eliminates the padding-left on the grid-elements. But for me this seems to be an unstylish solution. I wonder, because on another website it worked without such a hack: http://planilux.com/

Comment: don't remove the padding on grid elements, but the container that is containing them

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've solved it! I've had 
    .row {
        margin:0;
        }
in my stylesheet. This code eliminated the following bootstrap code:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Thanks!!!